# Instagram redirect Uri scheme for Android? iOS scheme is not accepted.

Tags: android, instagram

After trying to authorize with the Instagram API, the app breaks with an error

```
 redirect uri does not match registered redirect uri
```

By searching the SO, I can see that iOS users can resolve this by formatting the Uri as `ig+client_id+://authorize`. This fails on Android.

I also checked the project [android-instagram-oauth](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth) which use `instagram://connect` scheme. But this scheme breaks in my app as well.

What scheme shall I use for Android?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android the redirect URL has to be taken from the registered application on Instagram Developer. That is the only way it will work.

After I used that URL, the error vanished.